# Weird print showing up in knitr PDF

Tags: r, data.table, knitr

In a R Sweave file (.Rnw), when I compile the PDF using knitr, there are unwanted *things* printing. Its hard to explain exactly whats going on. I'm thinking that it's a result of using the data.table package and dplyr package but I haven't been able to find any other examples of this. However, I'm not even exactly sure what I could search for.

Here's a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

I honestly don't really know what else to say except that I would like to figure out how to get rid of it. If someone thinks this is a simple problem, instead of just downvoting, could you point me in the right direction of where to do some research on this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1}}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
library(stringr)
library(RODBC)
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(data.table)

rw1 <- c("File1", "File1", "File1", "File2", "File2", "File2", "File3", "File3", "File3", "File1", "File1", "File1", "File2", "File2", "File2", "File3", "File3", "File3", "File1", "File1", "File1", "File2", "File2", "File2", "File3", "File3", "File3")
rw2 <- c("0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03")
rw3 <- c("Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final")
rw4 <- c(123, 456, 789, 312, 645, 978, 741, 852, 963, 369, 258, 147, 753, 498, 951, 753, 915, 438, 978, 741, 852, 963, 369, 258, 147, 753, 498)
rw5 <- c("01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12")
rw6 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
rw7 <- c("Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release")
rw8 <- c("None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "Cannot Connect to Database", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None")


Testdf = data.frame(rw1, rw2, rw3, rw4, rw5, rw6, rw7, rw8)
colnames(Testdf) <- c("FileName", "Version", "Category", "Value", "Date", "Number", "Build", "Error") 

@

\title{Report}


\author{Current version}

\maketitle


\section{Report Summary}
This report documents the results 

<<Benchmarks,echo=FALSE>>=
library(ggplot2)
# library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

versions<-unique(Testdf[order(Testdf$Number), ][,2])

# Testdf %<>%
#     group_by(FileName) %>%
#     mutate(Benchmark = Value[which(Category == "Time" & Number == min(Number))]) %>%
#   ungroup()
setDT(Testdf)
Testdf[, Benchmark := Value[which.min(Number[Category == "Time"])], by = FileName]

Testdf$Version<-factor(Testdf$Version, levels = versions)
Testdf$Deviation<-Testdf$Value- Testdf$Benchmark
Testdf$DeviationP<-(Testdf$Value- Testdf$Benchmark)/Testdf$Benchmark



g<-ggplot(subset(Testdf, Category == 'Time') , aes(color = Value, x = Version, y = DeviationP, group = FileName)) + 
  geom_line(size=.25) + geom_point(aes(shape = Build), size = 1.5) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,15)) + stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom="line") + 
  ylab("Run Time Deviation from Benchmark (min)") +  
  scale_colour_gradient(name = 'Run Time (min)',low = 'blue', high = 'red') + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-105,105)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 90, vjust = .5)) + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 1)) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -0.1)) + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),"mm"))
g

@


\end{document}
```

Comment: Downvotes are probably because you haven't shared anything but a screenshot--no code. The expectation is usually for **minimal reproducible** examples,  your example is neither. Nor have you shown anything you may have tried to solve the problem. I never really used Sweave, but in knitr there are many chunk options that provide fine control over this sort of thing, and I'm pretty sure Sweave is similar in that respect.

Comment: @Gregor The reason being that I was having a hard time creating a reproducible example. I'm making an edit though that should take care of that.

Comment: This doesn't look like Sweave, it looks like knitr. If it's knitr I can answer.

Comment: knitr has been giving me trouble. I'd be very grateful if you can help.

Comment: Which version of `data.table` are you using please?

Comment: @Arun I'm using 1.9.4

Comment: David, thanks. Could you use the exact code you used before (without doing `Testdf <-`), but on `1.9.5`, which you can install by following [these instructions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).. Also what's your R version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things going on here. The table that's printing out is from your line:

```
Testdf[, Benchmark := Value[which.min(Number[Category == "Time"])], by = FileName]
```

That line both assigns the `Benchmark` column *and* returns the modified table. You can fix it two ways:

1. Assign the output to the same variable (or another, doesn't actually matter):

   ```
   Testdf <- Testdf[, Benchmark := Value[which.min(Number[Category == "Time"])], by = FileName]
   ```
2. Avoid any results ever printing by adding `results = 'hide'` to the header of that knitr chunk:

   ```
   <<Benchmarks,echo=FALSE, results = 'hide'>>=
   ```

---

The black messages in italics are package startup messages from `library(dplyr)`. Again, two choices of how to fix it:

1. Hide just those messages by changing your dplyr-loading line to:

   ```
   suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
   ```
2. Hide all messages in the chunk by adding `message = FALSE` to the head of that chunk:

   ```
   <<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE, message=FALSE>>=
   ```

In both cases, note that you can change the default in all chunks by adding a chunk at the start with:

```
<<set_defaults, echo = FALSE>>=
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message = FALSE, results = 'hide')
@
```

Comment: Fantastic answer thank you very much. I've been scouring google but unsure how to search for "unwanted table print dplyr".

Comment: @David very happy to help. As others noted it would have been helpful to start by showing the code, and not just the output- it wouldn't have been possible to find the table printing problem just from the PDF output.

Comment: I can appreciate that. I didn't originally include code because I was having trouble figuring out which pieces were responsible and therefore all of my reproducible examples weren't reproducing it.